# In what ways does explicit package main perform differently than an implicit package main?

Tags: perl, package, require

I was under the impression that a file that starts

```
use constant FOO => rand();
```

was effectively

```
package main;
use constant FOO => rand();
```

However, if I have **two** files with the constant declaration above, and one file `require`s the other file everything will work, while the second one will generate a warning.

> Constant subroutine main::FOO redefined at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base/constant.pm line 171.

For reference, here is the code I'm using in `f1.pl`, and `f2.pl` is the same **but with the `require` removed.**

```
# in `f1.pl`
package main;
no warnings;
use constant FOO => rand();

package Other;
require "f2.pl"; # this line should be removed from f2.pl

1;
```

In what ways does an implicit `package main` work differently from an explicitly `package main`?

Comment: Which perl vesion is that? I can not reproduce this on 5.32.

Comment: With Perl 5.30.0 I get the warning only when the actual value for FOO in f1.pl and f2.pl differ. That makes IMHO sense. The behavior does not depend on whether I explicitly declare 'package main;' or not.

Comment: Same as @BarneySchmale on perl 5.28.1 - I get the warning if the values are different and no warning if they're the same. These results are identical for all combinations of implicit vs. explicit "package main" in one, both, or neither file.

Comment: @zdim,  'use constant;' does more magic than simply install subroutines. I assume that constant.pm has an explicit check that warns only when the redefinition of $main::FOO is with a different value.

Comment: I had to update the question, last night when I wrote this up I didn't provide enough context for it to be answered. That was my bad. The second I knew what the problem was I was dealing with I updated the question. And literally 36 seconds after I updated it before I could self answer it **Grinnz had typed a 54 word answer.** So we know he types 120 WPM? amirite?

Comment: @BarneySchmale But the point was about `main::` namespace (really regardless of whether it complains about "same" sub or not). Doesn't matter now once the Q changed (even as it's a small change), I'm removing that comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package statement is less a declaration and more an action on that lexical scope. A file with `package main;` will switch to that package, regardless of what the current package is when it is required; without it, it will execute in the context of the package that was active when it was required.

Comment: This is exactly what the confusion, re: *without it, it will execute in the context of the package that was active when it was required.* IE. **there is no implicit package main** except on script-entry.

Comment: Or more specifically, on interpreter start.